# If $f'(x)$ exists at a point $P$, then $f(x)$ is continuous at this point. Proof.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification, continuity, alternative-proof

All the books which I've seen so far tend to proof it in a weird and over-complicated manner.

Let me try my own way.

So we know that $\lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{f(x + \delta) - f(x)}{\delta}$ exists.

Let $f'(x) = D$.

Thus: $$\lim_{\delta \to 0}\big(f(x + \delta) - f(x)\big) = \lim_{\delta \to 0}D \times \lim_{\delta \to 0}\delta$$

Since 1) $\lim_{\delta \to 0}D = D$ and 2) infinite small sequence $\lbrace\delta\rbrace$ multiplied by constant $D$ remains infinite small:

$$\lim_{\delta \to 0}\big(f(x + \delta) - f(x)\big) = 0$$
$$\lim_{\delta \to 0}f(x + \delta) = f(x)$$
... which is the definition of $f(x)$ being continuous at the $x$.

---

**Question**: is such a proof valid?

Comment: $$\begin{align}\lim_{\delta\to 0}\left(f(x+\delta)-f(x)\right)&=\lim_{\delta\to 0}\left(\left(\frac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta}\right)\,\times\delta\right)\\\\&=\lim_{\delta\to 0}\left(\frac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta}\right)\times\,\lim_{\delta\to0}\delta\\\\&=f'(x)\times 0\\\\&
=0\end{align}$$

Comment: @MarkViola I did not ask to provide yet another proof, I asked if the one I described is faultless.

Comment: The so-called "another proof" is precisely an improvement on yours in the OP.  You just need to tighten yours a bit.

Comment: @MarkViola I agree that the one you showed up is more beautiful, but currently I am more concerned with making sure there are no mistakes in my way of thinking. So the questions holds: is the proof I've wrote, tolerating it's "shape imperfection", valid?

Comment: The equation which you have wrote after "Thus:" is an invalid step. And this can be fixed as shown in comment from @MarkViola.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you asked, I will just point out where is not consistent to me.

1. You set $f'(x)=D$. Thus, $D=\lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac{f(x+\delta) - f(x)}{\delta}$ is a constant. However, you used $\lim_{\delta\to 0}D$ in later proof which is not consistent with your setting.
2. You did not say why
   $$
   \lim_{\delta \to 0} f(x+\delta) - f(x) = \lim_{\delta\to 0}D * \lim_{\delta\to 0}\delta
   $$
   Since this is not a conventional proof process, you may not easily get the above equality.